# Qt Quick Controls 2 on-screen Number pad on spinbox

Tags: qt, qtquickcontrols2

In a touchpanel application, is it possible to edit the integer value of a [qml SpinBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-spinbox.html), from QtQuickControls 2.0, in such a way that a numeric keypad appears on-screen and one can enter the exact value?

Or do you have any idea on how to embed [this predefined number pad](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-demos-calqlatr-content-numberpad-qml.html) in a customized spinbox, that should pop-up when the user taps on the integer number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestion. I came up with a first quick solution based on your idea and the number pad from the example section. I post it here, just in case it helps someone else as starting point. I am a QML beginner, so happy to get any improvements or corrections.

See attached screenshot of the numeric virtual touchpad appearing when clicking on the spinbox number

[image]

```
SpinBox {
    id: boxCommPos
    x: 50
    y: 50
    z: 0
    width: 200
    height: 50
    to: 360
    editable: false

    contentItem: TextInput {
        z: 1
        text: parent.textFromValue(parent.value, parent.locale)

        font: parent.font
        //color: "#21be2b"
        //selectionColor: "#21be2b"
        //selectedTextColor: "#ffffff"

        horizontalAlignment: Qt.AlignHCenter
        verticalAlignment: Qt.AlignVCenter

        readOnly: !parent.editable
        validator: parent.validator
        inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhFormattedNumbersOnly
    }

    Label {
        id: commUnits
        x: 125
        y: 0
        z: 3
        text: qsTr("º")
        font.pointSize: 16
        anchors.right: parent.right
        anchors.rightMargin: 45
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: padCommPos
        x: 40
        y: 0
        z: 2
        width: parent.width-x-x
        height: 50
        onClicked: touchpad.visible=true
    }
}

NumberTouchpad {
    id: touchpad
    x: 470
    y: -20
    z: 1
    scale: 0.90
    visible: false

    Rectangle {
        id: backrect
        x: -parent.x/parent.scale
        z: -1
        width: parent.parent.width/parent.scale
        height: parent.parent.height/parent.scale
        color: "#eceeea"
        opacity: 0.5
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
        }
    }
}
```

The file NumberPad.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Grid {
    columns: 3
    columnSpacing: 32
    rowSpacing: 16

    signal buttonPressed

    Button { text: "7" }
    Button { text: "8" }
    Button { text: "9" }
    Button { text: "4" }
    Button { text: "5" }
    Button { text: "6" }
    Button { text: "1" }
    Button { text: "2" }
    Button { text: "3" }
    Button { text: "0" }
    Button { text: "."; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: " " }
    Button { text: "±"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: "−"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: "+"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: "√"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: "÷"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    //Button { text: "×"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    Button { text: "C"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true }
    Button { text: "✔"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true; dimmable: true }
    Button { text: "X"; color: "#6da43d"; operator: true }

}
```

Display.qml

```
// Copyright (C) 2015 The Qt Company Ltd.
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.0    
Item {
    id: display
    property real fontSize: Math.floor(Screen.pixelDensity * 10.0)
    property string fontColor: "#000000"
    property bool enteringDigits: false
    property int maxDigits: (width / fontSize) + 1
    property string displayedOperand
    property string errorString: qsTr("ERROR")
    property bool isError: displayedOperand === errorString

    function displayOperator(operator)
    {
        listView.model.append({ "operator": operator, "operand": "" })
        enteringDigits = true
        listView.positionViewAtEnd()
        //console.log("display",operator);
    }

    function newLine(operator, operand)
    {
        displayedOperand = displayNumber(operand)
        listView.model.append({ "operator": operator, "operand": displayedOperand })
        enteringDigits = false
        listView.positionViewAtEnd()
        //console.log("newLine",operator);
    }

    function appendDigit(digit)
    {
        if (!enteringDigits)
            listView.model.append({ "operator": "", "operand": "" })
        var i = listView.model.count - 1;
        listView.model.get(i).operand = listView.model.get(i).operand + digit;
        enteringDigits = true
        listView.positionViewAtEnd()
        //console.log("num is ", digit);
    }

    function setDigit(digit)
    {
        var i = listView.model.count - 1;
        listView.model.get(i).operand = digit;
        listView.positionViewAtEnd()
        //console.log("setDigit",digit);
    }

    function clear()
    {
        displayedOperand = ""
        if (enteringDigits) {
            var i = listView.model.count - 1
            if (i >= 0)
                listView.model.remove(i)
            enteringDigits = false
        }
        //console.log("clearing");
    }

    // Returns a string representation of a number that fits in
    // display.maxDigits characters, trying to keep as much precision
    // as possible. If the number cannot be displayed, returns an
    // error string.
    function displayNumber(num) {
        if (typeof(num) != "number")
            return errorString;

        var intNum = parseInt(num);
        var intLen = intNum.toString().length;

        // Do not count the minus sign as a digit
        var maxLen = num < 0 ? maxDigits + 1 : maxDigits;

        if (num.toString().length <= maxLen) {
            if (isFinite(num))
                return num.toString();
            return errorString;
        }

        // Integer part of the number is too long - try
        // an exponential notation
        if (intNum == num || intLen > maxLen - 3) {
            var expVal = num.toExponential(maxDigits - 6).toString();
            if (expVal.length <= maxLen)
                return expVal;
        }

        // Try a float presentation with fixed number of digits
        var floatStr = parseFloat(num).toFixed(maxDigits - intLen - 1).toString();
        if (floatStr.length <= maxLen)
            return floatStr;

        return errorString;
    }

    Item {
        id: theItem
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height

        Rectangle {
            id: rect
            x: 0
            color: "#eceeea"
            height: parent.height
            width: display.width
        }
        /*Image {
            anchors.right: rect.left
            source: "images/paper-edge-left.png"
            height: parent.height
            fillMode: Image.TileVertically
        }
        Image {
            anchors.left: rect.right
            source: "images/paper-edge-right.png"
            height: parent.height
            fillMode: Image.TileVertically
        }

        Image {
            id: grip
            source: "images/paper-grip.png"
            anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.bottomMargin: 20
        }*/

        ListView {
            id: listView
            width: display.width
            height: display.height
            delegate: Item {
                height: display.fontSize * 1.1
                width: parent.width
                Text {
                    id: operator
                    font.pixelSize: display.fontSize
                    color: "#6da43d"
                    text: model.operator
                }
                Text {
                    id: operand
                    y:5
                    font.pixelSize: display.fontSize
                    color: display.fontColor
                    anchors.right: parent.right
                    anchors.rightMargin: 22
                    text: model.operand
                }
            }
            model: ListModel { }
        }

    }

}
```

calculator.qs

```
// Copyright (C) 2015 The Qt Company Ltd.

var curVal = 0
var memory = 0
var lastOp = ""
var previousOperator = ""
var digits = ""

function disabled(op) {
    if (op == "✔")
        display.fontColor="#000000"

    if (op=="X")
        return false
    else if (op == "✔" && (digits.toString().search(/\./) != -1  || digits.toString().search(/-/)!= -1 || parseInt(digits)>359)) {
        display.fontColor="#ff0000"
        return true
    }
    else if (digits == "" && !((op >= "0" && op <= "9") || op == "."))
        return true
    else if (op == '=' && previousOperator.length != 1)
        return true
    else if (op == "." && digits.toString().search(/\./) != -1) {
        return true
    } else if (op == "√" &&  digits.toString().search(/-/) != -1) {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}

function digitPressed(op)
{
    if (disabled(op))
        return
    if (digits.toString().length >= display.maxDigits)
        return
    if (lastOp.toString().length == 1 && ((lastOp >= "0" && lastOp <= "9") || lastOp == ".") ) {
        digits = digits + op.toString()
        display.appendDigit(op.toString())
    } else {
        digits = op
        display.appendDigit(op.toString())
    }
    lastOp = op
}

function operatorPressed(op)
{
    if (disabled(op))
        return
    lastOp = op

    if (op == "±") {
            digits = Number(digits.valueOf() * -1)
            display.setDigit(display.displayNumber(digits))
            return
        }

    if (previousOperator == "+") {
        digits = Number(digits.valueOf()) + Number(curVal.valueOf())
    } else if (previousOperator == "−") {
        digits = Number(curVal.valueOf()) - Number(digits.valueOf())
    } else if (previousOperator == "×") {
        digits = Number(curVal) * Number(digits.valueOf())
    } else if (previousOperator == "÷") {
        digits = Number(curVal) / Number(digits.valueOf())
    }

    if (op == "+" || op == "−" || op == "×" || op == "÷") {
        previousOperator = op
        curVal = digits.valueOf()
        digits = ""
        display.displayOperator(previousOperator)
        return
    }

    if (op == "=") {
        display.newLine("=", digits.valueOf())
    }

    curVal = 0
    previousOperator = ""

    if (op == "1/x") {
        digits = (1 / digits.valueOf()).toString()
    } else if (op == "x^2") {
        digits = (digits.valueOf() * digits.valueOf()).toString()
    } else if (op == "Abs") {
        digits = (Math.abs(digits.valueOf())).toString()
    } else if (op == "Int") {
        digits = (Math.floor(digits.valueOf())).toString()
    } else if (op == "√") {
        digits = Number(Math.sqrt(digits.valueOf()))
        display.newLine("√", digits.valueOf())
    } else if (op == "mc") {
        memory = 0;
    } else if (op == "m+") {
        memory += digits.valueOf()
    } else if (op == "mr") {
        digits = memory.toString()
    } else if (op == "m-") {
        memory = digits.valueOf()
    } else if (op == "backspace") {
        digits = digits.toString().slice(0, -1)
        display.clear()
        display.appendDigit(digits)
    } else if (op == "✔") {
        window.visible=false
        boxCommPos.value=parseInt(digits)
        display.clear()
        curVal = 0
        memory = 0
        lastOp = ""
        digits = ""

    } else if (op == "X") {
        window.visible=false
        display.clear()
        curVal = 0
        memory = 0
        lastOp = ""
        digits = ""
    }

    // Reset the state on 'C' operator or after
    // an error occurred
    if (op == "C" || display.isError) {
        display.clear()
        curVal = 0
        memory = 0
        lastOp = ""
        digits = ""
    }
}
```

Button.qml

```
// Copyright (C) 2015 The Qt Company Ltd.

import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    id: button
    property alias text: textItem.text
    property color color: "#eceeea"

    property bool operator: false
    property bool dimmable: false
    property bool dimmed: false

    width: 30
    height: 50

    Text {
        id: textItem
        font.pixelSize: 48
        wrapMode: Text.WordWrap
        lineHeight: 0.75
        color: (dimmable && dimmed) ? Qt.darker(button.color) : button.color
        Behavior on color { ColorAnimation { duration: 120; easing.type: Easing.OutElastic} }
        states: [
            State {
                name: "pressed"
                when: mouse.pressed && !dimmed
                PropertyChanges {
                    target: textItem
                    color: Qt.lighter(button.color)
                }
            }
        ]
    }

    MouseArea {
        id: mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: -5
        onClicked: {
            if (operator)
                window.operatorPressed(parent.text)
            else
                window.digitPressed(parent.text)
        }
    }

    function updateDimmed() {
        dimmed = window.isButtonDisabled(button.text)
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        numPad.buttonPressed.connect(updateDimmed)
        updateDimmed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The numpad can be set to be invisible and put on top of everything, then you can have a function to enable its visibility and set it's target. When you are done with typing the number, you set the target value to the numpad value, and hide it again. This way you can target different spinboxes.

As of the actual method to request the keypad, you can put a `MouseArea` to fill the spinbox on top of it. Or you can make the mouse area narrower, so that the plus/minus buttons of the spinbox are still clickable.

Also keep in mind that numpad you have linked is not actually functional.